# Python: Correct Emacs header?

Tags: python, c++, emacs

If I had a python file that I wanted emacs to open in python mode, what would I put at the top of that `.py` file?

For example, if it was an `.h` file that I wanted emacs to open in c++ mode, I would put:

```
//===-------------------------------*- C++ -*-===//
```

What is the equivalent for python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `.py` file, Emacs should already know to open it with
the Python major mode.  Otherwise,
see
[this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/636/how-do-i-automatically-load-a-mode-for-a-specific-set-of-file-extensions).

If for any reason you need to be explicit about it, you can specify
[file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) at
the top of your file in a comment;
e.g.:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file name already ends with `.py`, you shouldn't have to do anything.  Emacs should pick the right mode based on the extension.  Or if the file starts with a `#!` interpreter specification for `python`, Emacs should pick the right mode based on that.

Anyway, if you want to set the mode explicitly, add a comment containing `-*- mode: python -*-` on the first line of the file — or if the first line specifies a Python interpreter, you can put the comment on the second line instead.

So your file would start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- mode: python -*-
```

You can find more information and examples in the [Specifying File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) section of the Emacs manual.